# Compile error with Fortran program calling c++ function

Tags: c++, fortran90

I'm trying to link a C++ function at compile time into a Fortran program. I'm compiling with mpif90 using a make file. I add the C++ object file to object files list within the latter. The function compiles fine on its own via

g++ -c -o quenchf.o quenchf.cpp

but when I add the .o file to the make file for my Fortran program file I get the error:

quenchf.o: In function `Optim::Optim(double, double, int, int)':
quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x1348): undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned long)'
quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x1359): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x136d): undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned long)'
quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x1381): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x1395): undefined reference to`operator new[](unsigned long)'
quenchf.o:quenchf.cpp:(.text+0x13a9): more undefined references to `operator new[](unsigned long)' follow
quenchf.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
make: *** [ljnpt.exe] Error 1

Do I need to link in a C++ to Fortran library? I instantiate a C++ object in the c function so perhaps this is causing a problem.

Thanks for any help-

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this unless you use the mangled C++ name from Fortran.  It would be easier if you had a C front end to the C++ routine and called it from Fortran.  You will also need to link both the C and Fortran libraries.  That shouldn't be a problem but you must specify the C/C++ library explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any specific libraries to use?

Comment: You will need at least libgfortran, libc, libm and possibly libquadmath.

Answer (score 0):

You have not linked to the C++ runtime (which provides stuff like `operator new[](unsigned long)`). Trouble is, you'll need both the C++ and the Fortran runtime, and I'm not sure how to accomplish that, but there must be a way with the linker flags.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to find the libraries. Thanks for the help!